# Inserting information from an Inner Join

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

I currently have 3 tables and an inner join containing all the tables.

```
SELECT I.idInvoice
, C.idCustomer
, C.FirstName
, C.Surname
, P.idProduct
, P.Quantity
, I.Date
, P.PName
, P.Price
, I.QuantityOrdered
  FROM Invoice I
  JOIN Customer C 
    on I.idCustomer = C.idCustomer
  JOIN PRODUCT P 
    on I.idProduct = P.idProduct 
 LIMIT 0, 1000
```

I'm taking values from text labels, but the only problem is, I don't how to insert all the data into their respective tables. E.g. FirstName into Customer and Quantity into Product.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it shows your entire query. You only showed us part.

Comment: @O.Jones I updated it there now, my bad!

Comment: make 3 INSET and grab the data and insert the need information. as we don't see your tables, we can not help you

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Meaningless?  Hmm.... "Hey, 25-year-old piece of highly optimized software, give me 1000 rows of this stuff.  You pick the thousand ...."  Tha's not meaningless, @Strawberry. That means "hey, software, torture the next person to work on this stuff."